# How to access class variable in callback in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my current code:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BLE} from 'ionic-native';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/list/list.html'
})
export class ListPage { 
  devices: Array<{name:string, id: string}>;

  constructor() {  
    this.devices=[];       
  } 
  startScan (){
    this.devices = []; // This "this" exists and works fine
    BLE.scan([],5).subscribe(
      (device)=>{        
        if(device.name){
          this.devices.push({name:device.name,id:device.id});  // this.devices does not exists
        }             
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      }
      );
  }

  connectToDevice(device){
    BLE.connect(device.id).subscribe(success=>{
       console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
    });
  }
}
```

When calling startScan function I am trying to push returned device to array, however, this.devices is not available. I have tried saving this (self=this), but still with no luck. Can anyone help me to understand what i am missing?

UPDATE:
Setting

```
var self = this;
```

at the top of startScan() and then using it in .subscribe callback is the answer!

Comment: Where are you calling `startScan`?  It is possible that you have it bound to the wrong (or no) object.  Try adding `console.log(this)` at the top of `startScan` and see if it logs the object you are expecting.

Comment: startScan is called from view (html) on button click. this.devices does exists before I call BLE.scan, however, in a subscribe callback "this" becomes "subscribe" context

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how trying `self = this` at the top of `startScan()` didn't work for you. There's no logical reason it shouldn't work hehe. If you do that, and then `console.log(self)` inside of the subscribe callback, what do you get? -----
Secondly, have you tried making a variable that references, not`this`, but `this.devices` specifically? Maybe like `var _devices = this.devices;` after the declaration in startScan. Then `_devices.push(...` in the subscribe. Let us know!

Comment: I must be going mad.... Tried putting var self = this; and it worked this time.... I am sure I have tried this before as this would be something I would do writing javascript. So, yeah, it works :) it does not update view though when pushing, but i am sure its angular related. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! Though, as it's Typescript, shouldn't it be `let self = this;`? That worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 13):

> this.devices is not available

A common issue. Change `startScan` to an arrow function:

```
startScan = () => {
    this.devices = [];
    BLE.scan([],5).subscribe(
      (device)=>{        
        if(device.name){
          this.devices.push({name:device.name,id:device.id});  // this.devices does not exists
        }             
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      }
      );
  }
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/arrow-functions

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have already tried this. "this.devices" is already available when I call "startScan", the problem is with "BLE.scan", in subscribe callback, "this" referrers to "subscribe" context

Comment: link is broken dude :(

Comment: Link fixed now 

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code, it add characters to html textarea with button click event.

HTML

```
<div class="console-display">
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textAreaContent" name="mainText"></textarea>
    <div class="console-keys">
        <button (click)="getKeyInput($event)" name="key01" type="button" value="1">1</button>
        <button (click)="getKeyInput($event)" name="key02" type="button" value="2">2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
export class HomeComponent {
  tempString = "64";
  getKeyInput(event){
    let self = this;
    manageTextArea(self, event.target.value, this.textAreaContent);
  }
}

function manageTextArea(self , ch : string, textArea : string): void {
  if (checkCharacter_Number(ch)){
    self.textAreaContent += ch;
  }
  console.log(self.tempString);
}
```

It works fine.